# Some issues with an image carousel (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html, advanced-custom-fields

I'm making a image carousel to get some more experience.
I have an acf gallery in the back-end where i add my images.

This is the code that i use here:

```
<div class="images">

        <img id="carousel_images_top" src="" alt="">
        <div class="top_button next">Next</div>
        <div class="top_button prev">Prev</div>

    </div>

    <script>
        var imageList = [];
        <?php
            $images = get_field('image_carousel');

            foreach($images as $img) {
                echo "imageList.push('" . $img['url'] . "');";
            }

        ?>

        var imageTag = document.querySelector('#carousel_images_top');
        imageTag.src = imageList[0];
        function next() {
            console.log(imageTag.src)
            var curIndex = imageList.indexOf(imageTag.src);
            imageTag.src = imageList[(curIndex+1) % imageList.length];
        };
        function prev() {
            console.log(imageTag.src)
            var curIndex = imageList.indexOf(imageTag.src);
            imageTag.src = imageList[(curIndex-1 + imageList.length) % imageList.length];
        };
        document.querySelector('.next').addEventListener('click', next);
        document.querySelector('.prev').addEventListener('click', prev);
    </script>
```

I can see the first image in the array, and i can go back one to see the last one, but I can't go more than one back, and then forward to the first one again.
I do not get any errors at all, and I have tried to find out where the error is, but in the array, all of my 6 images is listed and the buttons are working.

I'm guessing there is an error in the curIndex variable, but I can't realy see what.
Anyone that can have a quick look and point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Static Template</title>
  </head>
  <body>
   <div class="images">
        <img id="carousel_images_top" src="" alt="">
         <p>Current Index: <span id="currentindex"></span></p>
          <div class="top_button next">Next</div>
         <div class="top_button prev">Prev</div>
   </div>
 
   <script>
         var imageList = [
            'https://tse1-mm.cn.bing.net/th?id=OIP.2bdrFgmVuK6LO0ggJdNPZAHaFP&w=152&h=105&c=8&rs=1&qlt=90&dpr=1.5&pid=3.1&rm=2',
            'https://tse1-mm.cn.bing.net/th?id=OIP.yP3sLQkAOswh1wDZq21NtwHaFj&w=144&h=105&c=8&rs=1&qlt=90&dpr=1.5&pid=3.1&rm=2',
            'https://tse1-mm.cn.bing.net/th?id=OIP.FEUTSwbKW9ndBYzd-oI8OQHaIN&w=99&h=105&c=8&rs=1&qlt=90&dpr=1.5&pid=3.1&rm=2',
            ];
 
         var imageTag = document.querySelector('#carousel_images_top');
          var currentindexTag = document.getElementById('currentindex');
         imageTag.src = imageList[0];
         function next() {
             //console.log(imageTag.src)
             var curIndex = imageList.indexOf(imageTag.src);
             imageTag.src = imageList[(curIndex+1) % imageList.length];
              currentindexTag.innerHTML = curIndex;
         };
         function prev() {
             //console.log(imageTag.src)
             var curIndex = imageList.indexOf(imageTag.src);
             imageTag.src = imageList[(curIndex-1 + imageList.length) % imageList.length];
              currentindexTag.innerHTML = curIndex;
         };
         document.querySelector('.next').addEventListener('click', next);
         document.querySelector('.prev').addEventListener('click', prev);
   </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Follow the code you write, the images replacement does work correctly except the input of images array has same url.

Because the [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-CN/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) method returns the first index at which a given element can be found in the array, or -1 if it is not present.

```
var images = ['1.png', '1.png', '1.png'];

//no matter how many times to execute images.indexOf('1.png'), it's always return 0.
```

So, the better solution is that replacing of the `curIndex` with a global number, like below:

```
var curIndex = 0;

function prev() {
    ...
    curIndex -= 1
}

function next() {
    ...
    curIndex += 1;
}
```

This solution should be avoiding the problem you meet.

---

That's an example and it makes some evidences for the correct of your script.

There are two directions to find the problem is. One, to check the images input, and another, try to [debug](https://javascript.info/debugging-chrome) the code in reality environment.

---

Comment: Thanks. I will take a look at this once i get home and can test the code again.

Comment: Could not get this to work. If i check my imageList array i get all my 6 images. Different URL's. Then i check the curren index of that url in my carousel. Then i go one up or one down when i press next / prev. And it also checks the length. This was working a few weeks ago, and now it does not.

Comment: It did work, best to do debugging in the environment the bug you got, because as the conditions here, all of the scripts are displaying correctly...